# I can't find bert base uncased in my conda environment after installing tokenizers

Tags: anaconda, data-science

I'm working on a sentiment extractor with bert-base-uncased and am getting an error.
I `pip install tokenizers` and am using:

```
import tokenizers
import os

MAX_LEN = 128
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 32
VALID_BATCH_SIZE = 16
EPOCHS = 10
BERT_PATH = "bert-base-uncased"
MODEL_PATH = "model.bin"
TRAINING_FILE = "../input/train.csv"
TOKENIZER = tokenizers.BertWordPieceTokenizer(
    os.path.join(BERT_PATH, "vocab.txt"),
    lowercase=True
)
```

How to use find the location of your models after installing in a new conda environment. thanks.

```
Exception: Error while initializing WordPiece
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put it like this:

```
'{BERT_PATH}/vocab.txt'
```

P.S. as you have added that bert model into the system so path contains slashes.